# Firebase Analytics dashboard - Save changes in comparison

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I've added some comparison in my Firebase Analytics dashboard but its not saved after i close the browser and i cant find any save button.

[image]

is it possible to save changes in the dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the URL, it has all the settings. I know it is not exactly what you asked, but it helps you not to set up everything again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Maybe something has changed. But as for today, this kind of settings is not present in the URL.

Comment: i just tested this and it does in fact save comparison settings in the URL. i tested with single and multiple comparisons and all variations i tested successfully loaded the analytics with the correct comparisons applied